Programmatically add an alias to an enum
Consider the following:
   class DayOfWeek( Enum ):
       SUN = 0
       MON = 1
       TUE = 2
       WED = 3
       THU = 4
       FRI = 5
       SAT = 6

I now need to add an alias but the _add_alias_ member function only accepts 1 value.
And PyDocs do not show how to programmatically add a new enumeration that is an alias of an existing value.
An example of what I want to do is this:
if  pay_day_is_friday():
    DayOfWeek._add_alias_( "PAYDAY",  DayOfWeek.FRI )
elif pay_day_is_monday():
    DayOfWeek._add_alias_( "PAYDAY",  DayOfWeek.MON )


And I am probably naive (I never took the time to understand what an Enum is in python, other than just a class acting as a namespace holding constants), but what is wrong with DayOfWeek.PAYDAY=DayOfWeek.MON?

_add_alias_() doesn't take any parameters. I'm not sure how it's supposed to be used, but the underscores around the method name imply that it's not intended for public use. The documentation is not helpful.

If you google "python enum add alias dynamically" you'll find a number of questions that show different ways, depending on your actual needs.

From an engineering standpoint, I would argue that PAYDAY = DayOfWeek.FRI is a better solution.  PAYDAY is not inherently a day of the week, so it should not be part of the enumeration.  It's just a global in your particular application.

To chrsig - That does not work.

to: Barmar - if you google "python enum add alias dynamically" - I did exactly that and found countless examples that are not what I want

Tim Robbers - PAYDAY = DayOfWeek.FRI - is not a better solution for me.  I am trying to create an ENUM that describes a type of data (class) - and depending upon the situation some name are sort of generic.   Consider a target for a Build system. On Windows a SHARED_LIB = a WIN_DLL, but on Linux/Mac it is a SO_FILE - and thus in this case I want the enum SHARED_LIB to be dynamically an alias for two different ENUM names.

It works on my machine. Unless (and that is not a pun. I sincerely don't know) you have another definition of "work": maybe I am missing a point (which was the reason why I started by saying "I may be naive") I don't know what your expect to work. But on my machine, you can DayOfWeek.PAYDAY=DayOfWeek.MON. And then use DayOfWeek.PAYDAY as a value (for example to store in a variable). Test an enum value against it: DayOfWeek.PAYDAY is DayOfWeek.MON is True. DayOfWeek.TUE is DayOfWeek.PAYDAY is not. So, what else is needed for this "alias"?

Also, one of my comments was removed (second time in a few day. Never happened before since I use this site. The 2 times I really don't think I was offensive. 1st time I was even the 1st one to upvote a hightly downvoted question and trying to help someone against adversity). I was, I think respectfully asking to indent the code. It is not much I know, but I think it is better if people can just copy and paste your code to try it. And there is 1 level of indentation in your class that prevent that.

"On Windows a SHARED_LIB = a WIN_DLL, but on Linux/Mac it is a SO_FILE - and thus in this case I want the enum SHARED_LIB to be dynamically an alias for two different ENUM names" I don't understand this. You want "SHARED_LIB" to be an alias for two names? Don't you mean values? And why not just SO_FILE = 1 and WIN_DLL = 1 (and if you want, SHARED_LIB = 1)? And why does this have to be dynamic and not part of the enum definition? It's not making sense and the days of week example isn't very useful.

DayOfWeek.FRI._add_alias_('PAYDAY')
_add_alias_ is not yet a public method, but it will probably become so in a future version.
However, I don't think PAYDAY is a good alias to add, unless it will always be Monday, or always be Friday -- in other words, if it's not going to switch values during the same program run.

MON/FRI - is just a simple generic example. My actual use case is something else that is more complex to describe so I gave a simple example in my question.

Also - add_alias does not work. It says: AttributeError: 'THINGS' has no attribute _add_alias_

@user3696153: _add_alias_ is a member method, not a class method; it also doesn't show up until Python 3.13.
